# Trouble finding the correct transformation (if exists) in matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, transformation, matrix-equations

> Let $\;A\in \mathbb M^{3\times 3}\;$ as $\;A=\begin{pmatrix} 
>                                                A_{11} \; A_{12} \;A_{13}\\
>                                                A_{21} \; A_{22} \;A_{23}\\
>                                                A_{31} \; A_{32} \;A_{33}\\
>                                               \end{pmatrix}\;$ and consider $\;x=\begin{pmatrix} 
>        x_1\\
>        x_2\\
>        x_3\\
>       \end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb R^3\;$. I need to find a transformation matrix $\;B\;$ such that: $\;ABx=-x_3 A_1 + A_2 + x_1 A_3\;$ where
>   $\;A_i=\begin{pmatrix} 
>        A_{1i}\\
>        A_{2i}\\
>        A_{3i}\\
>       \end{pmatrix}\;\;i=1,2,3\;$

**My attempt:**

If $\;B=\begin{pmatrix} 
        0\;\;\;0\;-1 \\ 
        0\;\;\;\frac{1}{x_2}\;\;0 \\
        1\;\;\;0\;\;\;0\\
        \end{pmatrix}\;$ then $\;ABx=\begin{pmatrix} 
                                               A_{11} \; A_{12} \;A_{13}\\
                                               A_{21} \; A_{22} \;A_{23}\\
                                               A_{31} \; A_{32} \;A_{33}\\
                                              \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
        0\;\;\;0\;-1 \\ 
        0\;\;\;\frac{1}{x_2}\;\;0 \\
        1\;\;\;0\;\;\;0\\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
       x_1\\
       x_2\\
       x_3\\
      \end{pmatrix}\;=\begin{pmatrix} 
                                               A_{11} \; A_{12} \;A_{13}\\
                                               A_{21} \; A_{22} \;A_{23}\\
                                               A_{31} \; A_{32} \;A_{33}\\
                                              \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 
       -x_3\\
       1\\
       x_1\\
      \end{pmatrix}\;=-x_3 \begin{pmatrix} 
       A_{11}\\
       A_{21}\\
       A_{31}\\
      \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 
       A_{12}\\
       A_{22}\\
       A_{32}\\
      \end{pmatrix} + x_1 \begin{pmatrix} 
       A_{13}\\
       A_{23}\\
       A_{33}\\
      \end{pmatrix}\;$

**Questions:**

Although I concluded to what I wanted, I'm a bit unsure if $\;B\;$ is indeed a transformation matrix.

1. If such a transformation exists, then what's its geometric meaning?
2. Instead of this $\;B\;$, could it be a rotation matrix ?

Any help would be valuable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that a typo? Should it be $ABx = -x_3A_1+x_2A_2+x_1A_3$ or something? As written, the problem is impossible.

Comment: @JackM No,unfortunately it's not a typo. Could you explain to me why is the problem impossible in this case?

Comment: Actually, it depends. Do we have a specific vector $x$, and you want a matrix $B$ such that the equation $ABx=...$ is true just for that one $x$, or do you want a matrix $B$ such that the equation is true for *all* $x$? The latter is impossible, the former is rather simple and can be solved by many different matrices $B$.

Comment: @JackM I want the equation to be true $\;\forall x \in \mathbb R^3\;$.Why is it impossible? The matrix $\;B\;$ as stated above doesn't have any geometric meaning,does it?

Comment: Okay, I have another question: are you looking for a single matrix $B$ that works for *all* $x$, or is $B$ allowed to depend on $x$? Currently your solution is of that second type.

Comment: @JackM I'm looking for a transformation matrix. To be honest, I would be very happy if this matrix was a rotation one. But in order to satisfy the given equation, the only matrix I could think of is the one that depends on $\;x\;$ and I don't know if this could be considered as a transformation in first place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67115/discussion-between-jack-m-and-kaithkolesidou).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is unsolvable for most matrices $A$. It's possible for matrices $A$ whose second column is all zeros.

We have a particular matrix $A$ and would like to find a matrix $B$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb R^3$:

$$ABx = A\tag{1}\begin{pmatrix}-x_3\\1\\x_1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

This is an equality between the functions $x\to ABx$ and the function of $x$ defined on the right hand side. The problem is that the function on the right hand side is non-linear (basically because of the $1$ in the second coordinate), so it can't be represented by a matrix $AB$. The problem with your solution is that $B$ depends on $x$.

If the second column of $A$ is not zero, then this is impossible. To see this, take $x=(0,\lambda,0)$. On the right you get $A_2$, and on the left you get $\lambda(AB)_2$, that is, $\lambda$ times the second column of $AB$. Thus we get $\forall \lambda,\ A_2=\lambda(AB)_2$. So, a constant on the left equals something non-constant on the right. Not possible - unless both sides are always equal to zero, so $A_2$ is the zero vector.